# The complexity of counting solutions to $x_1 + \dots + x_m = N$ in non-negative integers under constraints

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity

Consider the equation
$$x_1 + \dots + x_m = N$$
where $x_1,\dots,x_m \ge 0$ and under the additional constraints $x_k \le a_k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,m$.

**I'm interested in knowing whether the number of solutions to (1) can be found in sub-exponential time w.r.t. $m$.**

One way to solve it would be to recursively lower the number of constraints by subtracting the number of solutions with constraints $0 \le x_1 \le a_1, \dots, 0 \le x_{m-1} \le a_{m-1}, x_{m-1} > a_{m-1}$ from the solutions without the constraint on $x_{m-1}$. Since constraints of type $x_j > a_j$ can  be dealt by substituting $x_j + a_j + 1$ for $x_j$, and because there is a closed formula for the case without constraints at all, we'll get the job done in about $2^m$ steps. This is basically the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: I interpret this as a count of partitions of N into at most m parts not exceeding a 'capping' partition a_1 .. a_m. Since you ask for a count as function of m, I wonder how you define the capping 'a'-partition as function of m.

Comment: @Wouter M.: The count depends on the capping partition, not just $m$, but the time to compute that count has an upper bound that only depends on $m$. I'm interested in how fast we can actually compute the number for any $m$-sized capping partition $a_1,\dots,a_m$.

Comment: Doesn't this boil down to trimming partition cap for (capN-bigN) times and counting the union of the resulting partitions? With 'trimming' I mean removing a corner cell in all allowable ways.

Comment: Maybe http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161148/the-number-of-partitions-between-two-fixed-partitions is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the coefficient of $y^N$ in $$(1+y+\cdots+y^{a_1})\times\cdots\times(1+y+\cdots+y^{a_m})$$ Rewrite the product as $$(1-y^{a_1+1})\times\cdots\times(1-y^{a_m+1})(1-y)^{-m}$$ Expand $$(1-y)^{-m}=\sum_0^N{n+m-1\choose m-1}x^n+{\rm\ higher\ order\ terms}$$ Now multiply in turn by $1-y^{a_1+1},\dots,1-y^{a_m+1}$. You can always discard terms in $y^s$ with $s\gt N$ along the way.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought about this. :) Just checking I understood everything correctly: the number of operations needed using this method would be $O(m N)$?

Comment: Looks like it to me.